# Showing that the angular momentum transforms as a vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, vectors, tensor-calculus, covariance

I define a vector as any object $(a_i,a_j, a_k)$ such that it transforms the same way as the coordinates themselves. That is if $x'_i = R_{ij}x_j$, then $a'_i = R_{ij}a_j$. Please correct me if this is not a proper definition. (EDIT: As pointed out in the comment, I may have to restrict $R$ to proper rotations so $det(R) = 1$.)

With this in mind, how can I show that the angular momentum is a vector? I have $l_i = \epsilon_{ijk}r_jp_k$. On one side, I show that

$l'_i = R_{ij}l_j = R_{ij}\epsilon_{jlm}r_l p_m$

But this should somehow be the same as the transformed $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{p}$. That is $l'_i = \epsilon_{ijk}r'_jp'_k = \epsilon_{ijk}R_{jl} r_l R_{km}p_m$

How do I reconcile these two?

Comment: Angular momentum does not transform as a vector. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector?wprov=sfla1

Comment: I see. If I add the additional condition of det(R) = 1, then does my question make sense?

Comment: I think that in that case is correct.